# Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers and $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive real numbers. Then show that

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

My work: Since $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{a_n}$ is convergent, so its sequential partial sum, denoted by $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x_k}{a_k}$ is convergent. Now using Cauchy criteria for series convergence, there exists $n>m\geq N$ such that for any given $\epsilon>0$, we have $|S_n-S_m|<\epsilon$
for all $n>m\geq N$. Now for $n>N$, $$|\frac{1}{a_n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}x_k|=|\frac{1}{a_n}(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}x_k+\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}x
_k)|=|\frac{1}{a_n}(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}x_k+\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}a
_k(S_k-S_{k-1}))|$$

I know that $\frac{1}{a_n}(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}x_k)$ goes to zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$. How can I estimate the second summation. We also given that $a_n$ is monotonocally increasing positive sequence.

Please give some hint or idea.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma

Comment: Compare also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910439/does-sum-i-1-infty-a-i-i-infty-imply-that-a-i-has-cesaro-mean-zero.